# How Many Hours Do You Need To Work To Buy An Iphone?

Tags: price

I have often seen pictures like this - in different countries around the world, how many hours do you need to work before you can buy an Iphone:

[image]

**My Question:** Is there a generalization to this concept?

For example, suppose I am a lazy person that does not like to work. I want to know, in which country in the world will give me the most value for every hour I work?

To be a bit more general, suppose we took the average job in a given country. We know how much the average job earns per hour. Then, suppose we took the price of some "economic market basket" (e.g. food, shelter, energy) in this country - we could see how many hours the average person would be required to work to afford this basket. Then, we could repeat this calculation for a list of different countries (e.g. while adjusting the wages and price for the average job and a comparable basket). Finally, in theory, I would be able to know : **On average, in which country do I need to work the least to afford the most?**

Is there some economic quantity that measures this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(PPP)_per_capita

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_average_wage Here the average wage is adjusted for prices, which is what you want